# How does adding a record in db using Linq to SQL work?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I am just learning Linq to SQL and from an example I added a record in db by passing a custom type object. For example to add a new user in users table I did:

```
db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I couldn't get how Linq know which property value should be added in which column ?

Is there any better way then this to add a new record in db using Linq ?

Kindly also mention how I can add if I am not using custom types (DTO) ?

so thanks for your precious time and sharing.

Comment: You created mapping first, no?

Comment: Andrey I have not created mapping consciously may be that I did it and I dont know. I just add tables in designer.

Comment: Yes, your designer creates the mappings for you.  See my answer

Comment: @Adam Rackis, kindly explain a point that I commented under your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DBML file spells out how all your objects' properties are mapped to your DBMS.  the database tables/views you add to the DBML causes corresponding classes to be created for you—like your `Users` class—whose properties are decorated with attributes telling L2S how to handle all the ORM mappings

Under your DBML file should be a [whatever].designer.cs file that shows this.  Here's a sample of what it should look like:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Invoices")]
public partial class Invoice : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private long _InvoiceId;

    private string _InvoiceNum;

    private decimal _TotalTaxDue;
```

snip

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_InvoiceId", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public long InvoiceId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._InvoiceId;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._InvoiceId != value))
            {
                this.OnInvoiceIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._InvoiceId = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("InvoiceId");
                this.OnInvoiceIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_InvoiceNum", DbType="VarChar(15)")]
    public string InvoiceNum
    {
        get
        {
            return this._InvoiceNum;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._InvoiceNum != value))
            {
                this.OnInvoiceNumChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._InvoiceNum = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("InvoiceNum");
                this.OnInvoiceNumChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

etc

Comment: @Adam thanks, I have seen designer file but still I couldn't get how custom objects are mapped with db columns. can you please specify. Actually I am not getting for two strings db columns where I can map or change mapping. Please guide.

Comment: Expand the dbml file, then click on the .designer.cs file.  Read through that, and you should see your classes defined, with their properties decorated with attributes, like `[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_InvoiceNum", DbType="VarChar(15)")]`  This is how linq knows how to map your objects to your database

Comment: @Adam thanks again. I can see in designer file all columns of database table are mentioned. Similarly events are mentioned on every db column (changing and changed events). Please don't be disturbed by me. In events only mention is datatype of parameter and parameter name is value (like  partial void OnIdChanging(int value);) Where Linq map custom type object property with db column.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by custom type object property with db column.

Comment: @Adam I meant suppose I have a DTO User which has 3 properties id, name and address. Like for adding a new user I made a class that has 3 properties id,name and address.

Comment: If you have a DTO that has your user properties, you need to copy those values over to your LINQ User object, so it can be inserted into the database.  For larger examples than just a 3-property DTO, you can use a mapper like ValueInject or AutoMapper